# Python MP3 player tkinter crashes

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code that plays mp3s using python, but the tkinter window crashes and wont stay open.I'm using the latest version of python. I found this code online but it seems to be old. I was thinking it isn't working beacuse it's not compatible. I have run tkinter in the past so I know that's not the problem. Does anybody know the solution to this problem. I'm working on Mac OS, I can send the crash report if needed.

```
    from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
    import pygame
    from tkinter.filedialog import *
    from tkinter import *

    pygame.init()

class FrameApp(Frame):
  def __init__(self,master):
    super(FrameApp, self).__init__(master)

    self.grid()
    self.paused = False
    self.playlist = list()
    self.actual_song = 0

    self.b1 = Button(self, text="play", command=self.play_music, width=20)
    self.b1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    self.b2 = Button(self, text="previous", command=self.previous_song,
                     width=20)
    self.b2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    self.b3 = Button(self, text="toggle", command=self.toggle, width=20)
    self.b3.grid(row=3, column=0)

    self.b4 = Button(self, text="next", command=self.next_song, width=20)
    self.b4.grid(row=4, column=0)

    self.b5 = Button(self, text="add to list", command=self.add_to_list,
                     width=20)
    self.b5.grid(row=5, column=0)

    self.label1 = Label(self)
    self.label1.grid(row=6, column=0)

    self.output = Text(self, wrap=WORD, width=50)
    self.output.grid(row=8, column=0)

    # set event to not predefined value in pygame
    self.SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

    # TODO: Make progressbar, delete songs from playlist, amplify volume

def add_to_list(self):
    """
    Opens window to browse data on disk and adds selected songs to play list
    :return: None
    """
    directory = askopenfilenames()
    # appends song directory on disk to playlist in memory
    for song_dir in directory:
        print(song_dir)
        self.playlist.append(song_dir)
    self.output.delete(0.0, END)

    for key, item in enumerate(self.playlist):
        # appends song to textbox
        song = EasyID3(item)
        song_data = (str(key + 1) + ' : ' + song['title'][0] + ' - '
                     + song['artist'][0])
        self.output.insert(END, song_data + '\n')

def song_data(self):
    """
    Makes string of current playing song data over the text box
    :return: string - current song data
    """
    song = EasyID3(self.playlist[self.actual_song])
    song_data = "Now playing: Nr:" + str(self.actual_song + 1) + " " + \
                str(song['title']) + " - " + str(song['artist'])
    return song_data

def play_music(self):
    """
    Loads current song, plays it, sets event on song finish
    :return: None
    """
    directory = self.playlist[self.actual_song]
    pygame.mixer.music.load(directory)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(self.SONG_END)
    self.paused = False
    self.label1['text'] = self.song_data()

def check_music(self):
    """
    Listens to END_MUSIC event and triggers next song to play if current 
    song has finished
    :return: None
    """
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == self.SONG_END:
            self.next_song()

def toggle(self):
    """
    Toggles current song
    :return: None
    """
    if self.paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        self.paused = False
    elif not self.paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        self.paused = True

def get_next_song(self):
    """
    Gets next song number on playlist
    :return: int - next song number
    """
    if self.actual_song + 2 <= len(self.playlist):
        return self.actual_song + 1
    else:
        return 0

def next_song(self):
    """
    Plays next song
    :return: None
    """
    self.actual_song = self.get_next_song()
    self.play_music()

def get_previous_song(self):
    """
    Gets previous song number on playlist and returns it
    :return: int - prevoius song number on playlist
    """
    if self.actual_song - 1 >= 0:
        return self.actual_song - 1
    else:
        return len(self.playlist) - 1

def previous_song(self):
    """
    Plays prevoius song
    :return: 
    """
    self.actual_song = self.get_previous_song()
    self.play_music()


    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("350x500")
    app = FrameApp(root)

    while True:
     **strong text**# runs mainloop of program
     app.check_music()
     app.update()
```

Comment: Without some info about the crash (when does it happen/triggering, some traceback..), I doubt there can be much help!

Comment: Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8cd9a598a0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Comment: Getting a NSException